# How to find records from MySQL where only part of fields meet the conditions?

Tags: mysql

I'm a MySQL rookie and I'm stuck on the following problem.
I have a table and there're 3 numeric value fields in it. I call them A, B, and C.
I want to find records where there're at least two values > 60.
One way to solve the problem is

```
SELEC * FROM table WHERE (A>60 AND B>60) OR (A>60 AND C>60) OR (B>60 AND C>60) OR (A>60 AND B>60 AND C>60)
```

But I don't think this is an elegant way. There is only 3 values. If there are 10 or 20 value fields in the table, and I also want to find records where there're at least two values > 60. Using the above way to solve the problem would be very ugly.
So is there a better way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `GREATEST` and `LEAST` functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    GREATEST(A, B, C) > 60 AND                              -- largest value
    (A + B + C) - GREATEST(A, B, C) - LEAST(A, B, C) > 60;  -- 2nd largest value
```

### Demo

But honestly the version you have right now is almost as concise as what I wrote above.

Comment: Hi Tim, do you know if there is a limit of elements to be used in those functions? There is no mention of it in the DOCs. Great answer though +1

Comment: @JorgeCampos Good question, it certainly works for 3 arguments, and the MySQL documentation gives an example with 5.  Beyond this, I don't know.

Comment: Ok, thank you, will do some testing on it and report back :)

Comment: Well it seems that it depends on the value of the `max_allowed_packet` configuration when I used a really big amount of elements it returned me the `Error Code: 1153. Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet'`

Comment: So then there may not be a formal limit on these functions.  Rather, they die when the packet size being sent to MySQL overloads.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I think that should be explicit in the Docs though.